# Is there a maximum number of "favorite tags" a user can have?

Tags: discussion, watched-tags

I noticed my list of favorite tags getting pretty long on my sidebar.  It made me question if there was a limit on how many favorite tags a user can have.  I checked the Arqade meta and meta.SO but there does not seem to be any mention of a max.

So is there a limit and, if so, what is that limit?

Comment: A note, in case you didn't know: favorite tags accept the `*` wildcard. So if you, for example, want to follow all the questions about [tag:call-of-duty], you can favorite [tag:call-of-duty*]. I do this to help keep my favorite tags a bit compacter for game series I have interest in. (Edit: though it apparently doesn't autoconvert to a tag in comments... interesting)

Comment: Technical answer: Yes*. Realistic Answer: *Not any limit worth worrying about.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: it would be stupid if there's one so low that you can trigger it

[image]

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to make sure.  If there was I might be inclined to clean things.... *shudder*

Comment: @Braiam - why would it be stupid if there was one? It would actually make sense from a technical point of view that there IS a hard limit, but I daresay we don't even have nearly enough tags to reach that number anyway.

Comment: @Robotnik because SE is flexible, and they have to be ready for someone ignoring/favoring a load of tags like in the screenshot.

Comment: Again, I daresay there IS a hard limit, but I bet there isn't enough tags across the whole network to hit said limit. Also did you go and favorite those tags just to make a point lol :-P

Comment: @Robotnik nah, I'm not that bored, [someone else yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217664/213575)

Comment: That's *nothing*. I'm somewhere around 800 ignored tags on Arqade.

Comment: @FEichinger well, you are bored...

Comment: Not true at all! ... Well, maybe kinda true. But that's not why I'm ignoring ALL TEH TAGS!

Comment: Yeh, minecraft is evil...